# mercurial pulling

Tags: mercurial, pull

I have a problem. Actually I want to push, but gives some error.

> error: unable to push: Push will not be performed as it would create
>   remote branches. You must first resync by doing a pull from the target
>   repository and merge.

Then, I want to pull and I get this error2.

> error2:
>
> Output: [comparing with
>   http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/itucs-blg361-2011-g03, searching
>   for changes, abort: Permission denied: /home/burak_bundle0]

Comment: Do you have permission on /home/burak_bundle0?

Comment: I dont understand. I have permission to push for this: http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/itucs-blg361-2011-g03 
Normally I could push before.

I didnt understand what does it mean "permission denied" can be about root on ubuntu?

Comment: The error message you received said "Permission denied: /home/burak_bundle0". That means that it was trying to read or write from the directory "/home/burak_bundle0" and did not have permission to do so.

Comment: what should I do?
Can I change this directory?

Comment: That depends on why it's trying to write to that directory (or file). Is that where your local repository is? Or is there a hook that's trying to write to that file? You might be better rewriting your question to include the actual output from your `pull` (and include details like your working directory, etc)

Comment: It looks very much like a server administration issue. A wild guess: Maybe someone accessed the repository with root permissions and now some parts of the repository are not accessible by regular users anymore? I had this before. You should contact your system administrator, ask him to check the file permissions.

Comment: The account in Mercurial is belong to me, I dont have any other problem with another computers when I try to pull and push, but when I do it on my computer I have this problem

Comment: OK. thank you. I did on terminal chmod 777 for /home than solved my problem

Comment: A word of advice - wildly changing file permissions (expecially on your home directory) is not a good solution. Some tools won't work correctly if you do that, and you open up various security issues. I'm glad it fixed your problem, but you should really work out what's actually going on under the covers and fix it more safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have permission on /home/burak_bundle0?

Comment: OK. thank you. I did on terminal chmod 777 for /home than solved my problem